# Firebase deploy an ViteJS project giving an error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 in main.jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, vite

I'm trying for the first time deploy an vitejs project to the firebase hosting, but i'm encountering this error: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (main.jsx:1)"

--

My project folder is like this:

[image]

and it shows this:

[image]

I've tried putting the whole project folder inside the build but it doesn't work.